# How to change setting in hierarchical styles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have following scenario.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shadows}
\tikzset{newEntity/.style={
        circular glow={fill=red},
    },
}

\tikzset{poseEstimate/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        fill=yellow
    },
}

\tikzset{
    newLastPoseEstimate/.style={
            poseEstimate,
            newEntity,
            shadow scale=2
           },
}


\tikzset{
    newLastPoseEstimate2/.style={
            poseEstimate,
            circular glow={fill=red,shadow scale=2}
           },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
    node[newLastPoseEstimate] {not working} ++(3,0)
    node[newLastPoseEstimate2] {working};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However I want to change the property `shadow scale` of the `circular glow` style but in the style `newLastPoseEstimate`. All other style which copy from `newEntity` should not be affected.

I added a new style `newLastPoseEstimate2` how I would like to have it. However the glow thing should be in some kind of base style. Hopefully you get my point.

[image]

Comment: Thx, I edited my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the nice MWE.

Every `pgfkeys` style, and thus every Ti*k*Z style `foo`, accepts one argument when defined with `foo/.style={...}`. Therefore, you can use the argument of your `newEntity` style to dynamically pass whatever options you want, such as `shadow scale=2`, inside the `circular glow={...}` options used by `newEntity`. In order not to break existing uses of `newEntity`, just define the default value of this argument as the empty token list. The value assigned to `newEntity/.default` is used whenever `newEntity` is called without an explicit value, for instance as in `\tikzset{newEntity}` as opposed to `\tikzset{newEntity=whatever}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tikzset{
  newEntity/.style={
    circular glow={fill=red, #1}, % here, we use the argument
    newEntity/.default={},        % it's empty by default
  },
  poseEstimate/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=yellow
  },
  newLastPoseEstimate/.style={
    poseEstimate,
    newEntity,                    % the default value is used here
  },
  newLastPoseEstimate2/.style={
    poseEstimate,
    newEntity={shadow scale=2},   % argument explicitly specified
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[newLastPoseEstimate] {working 1} ++(3,0)
      node[newLastPoseEstimate2] {working 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, nice solution.

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, in case you want to use more arguments, look for `.style 2 args`, `.style n args` and `.style args` in the Ti*k*Z & PGF manual.